# Chipmunk: how to delete a body?

Tags: oop, chipmunk

What's the right way to delete a Chipmunk body?  Simply calling `cpBodyFree` or `cpBodyDestroy` doesn't seem to work, as the body still shows up in the `cpSpaceEachBody` iteration.

```
if(body->p.y < -260 || fabsf(body->p.x) > 340) {
    /* body is permanently off the screen    */
    /* so it needs to be permanently deleted */
    cpBodyFree(body);      ??
    cpBodyDestroy(body);   ??
}
```

Comment: OK, for someone who's never heard of whatever you're talking about, that's a weird start to the question.

Comment: surprisingly, its not a Ruby library this time

Comment: @mmyers, it didn't look weird until you pointed it out.  Good thing it's not a package called My Coworkers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to delete a body:

1. if there's a shape associated with the body, remove the shape from the space and delete it.
2. remove the body from the space. ***(this is the part I was missing.)***
3. finally, delete the space if it is not needed anymore.

Here's how to make the Plink demo rain down a single shower of pentagons and clean them up when
they go off screen.

1. Add this line to the "//Add lots of pentagons" loop.  This is so we can free the shape attached to the body.

   ```
   body->data=shape;
   ```
2. remove the shape and body from the space, then free the shape and body.  It doesn't 
   seem to matter if you remove/free the shape first or the body first, so long as you 
   keep in mind that you lose the pointer to the shape when you free the body.  Change the **eachBody** function to:

   ```
   if (body->p.y < -260 ) {
       cpSpaceRemoveShape(space, body->data);
       cpSpaceRemoveBody(space, body);
       cpShapeFree(body->data);
       cpBodyFree(body);
   }
   ```

Comment: ok but you only delete the space if you don't want it anymore, right?   If you have other chipmunk bodies you need to keep the space, right?

Comment: ok, Im trying to call a method from within a static cpBool begin or preSolve chipmunk method.  I put this but of course it didn't work because its not c++ code but rather objC.  [self removeShield:shield];  How would I write that in C++?

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the [lib code](http://chipmunk-physics.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/cpBody.c)

```
void cpBodyDestroy(cpBody *body){}

void
cpBodyFree(cpBody *body)
{
    if(body){
        cpBodyDestroy(body);
        cpfree(body);
    }
}
```

Call `cpBodyFree` (it calls internally cpBodyDestroy internally.

UPDATE: Except in cases where you don't need the validation and the `cpfree(body)` call ; )

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure whether the shape has been added as static or not, may be this code will help a bit:

```
    if(shape != NULL)
    {
        int isStatic = 1;
        cpBody *bd = cpShapeGetBody(shape);
        if(bd != NULL)
        {
            if(!cpBodyIsRogue(bd) && !cpBodyIsStatic(bd)) //second condition is just to make sure
            {
                isStatic = 0;
                cpSpace *sp1 = cpBodyGetSpace(bd);
                if(sp1 != NULL)
                {
                    cpSpaceRemoveBody(sp1, bd); //remove body from space and then free it
                }
            }
            cpBodyFree(bd);
        }

        cpSpace *sp = cpShapeGetSpace(shape);
        if(sp != NULL)
        {
            if(isStatic)
                cpSpaceRemoveStaticShape(sp, shape);
            else
                cpSpaceRemoveShape(sp, shape); //remove shape from space and then free it
        }

        cpShapeFree(shape);
        shape = NULL;
    }
```